# Adding a custom class to php Echo (get_avatar - Wordpress)

Tags: php, css, wordpress

By default my avatar floats to the left, I'd like to add a custom class to avoid this from happening. I've tried:

**CODE:**

```
<?php 
   echo get_avatar( 'sam@moneynest.co.uk', $size = '40', $default = '<path_to_url>',  array('class' => 'avataronblog')); 
   ?>
```

**CSS:**

```
.avataronblog {
    float: none;
}
```

But had no luck - any advice?

Comment: If there is another CSS rule for `.avataronblog`, it could replace your rule. Try testing with `float: none !important;` to see if it works that way. If so, then it simply is that another CSS rule is overwriting your rule, and you either keep the `!important` argument or move your CSS to the bottom.

Comment: Thanks Exit, it's a custom class I've not used before. The float left comes from the output pulling in the class .avatar which adds a float. I don't want to remove it from that as its used elsewhere.

Comment: Is there a way to add in inline styling for this?

Comment: Well, I'd suggest using Chrome and pressing F12 to get to the developer tools. If you right click on your avatar, you will see all the CSS rules active on it, and from there determine if anything is causing issues and even try adding CSS rules live to see what affect they have. It's possible there is a secondary class definition or inherited rule is affecting it too.

Comment: Also, simply setting it to float none might not be everything you need. You might need to add something like `margin:0 auto;` to center it in the container that holds it. Plus, the container itself might not be sized to a full width. This is where the developer tools in Chrome are invaluable to examine what is actually going on.

Comment: Hey Exit, I have done that and I need to add a new class it is the float. You can see an example at: https://www.moneynest.co.uk/blog/ you can see my head/avatar floating to the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the documentation for `get_avatar`, the 4th argument is `alt` and the 5th is `args`. You simply have to push your 4th argument to the 5th.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar

```
echo get_avatar( 'sam@moneynest.co.uk', $size = '40', $default = '<path_to_url>', '', array('class' => 'avataronblog'));
```

I've simply added in a null value for `alt`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat. Also, I appreciate the explanation.